# Select Groups ID from table with specified members count

Tags: mysql

I have the following **example** data in my `members` table:

```
+----+----------+-----------+  
| id | users_id | groups_id |  
+----+----------+-----------+  
|  1 |        1 |         1 |  
|  2 |        2 |         1 |  
|  3 |        1 |         2 |  
|  4 |        2 |         2 |  
|  5 |        3 |         2 |  
+----+----------+-----------+
```

I want to select groups_id which contains exactly two specified members, which are for example, 1 and 2. I tried using this query:

```
SELECT groups_id 
FROM   members 
WHERE  users_id IN ( 2, 1 ) 
GROUP  BY groups_id 
HAVING Count(users_id) = 2;
```

but it still returns both `groups_id` 1 and 2.
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `users_id` is an `int` you can do:

```
SELECT groups_id 
FROM   members 
GROUP  BY groups_id 
HAVING MIN(users_id) = 1 AND MAX(users_id) = 2;
```

This will select `groups_id` values having exactly two related `users_id` values, `1` and `2`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/412af/3)

**Edit:**

For any two `user_id` values you can use the following query:

```
SELECT groups_id 
FROM   members 
GROUP  BY groups_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN users_id IN (1, 2) THEN users_id END) = 2
       AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN users_id NOT IN (1, 2) THEN users_id END) = 0
```

Comment: Yeah, it's `int`. How can I specify here that I'm looking for members with the ID 1 and 2?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal You can use the predicates specified in the `HAviNG` clause of my query.

Comment: Seems like your query will not work if I'm looking for groups with any two arbitrary values like 1 and 3.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal I tried to answer the question posted. If you have another question you can modify  your post accordingly.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal yes will work, you change 2 for 3... Just make sure the small value go on the `MIN` and the bigger value on the `MAX`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos my bad, 1 and 2 were for example. And I still tried the query, doesn't work as it should.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal The query does work as it should for values 1, 2. Please check the demo.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional count

So group have one `1` and one `2`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/412af/4)**

```
SELECT groups_id 
FROM   members 
GROUP  BY groups_id 
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN users_id = 1 THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN users_id = 2 THEN 1 END) = 1 
   AND COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: I'm still trying to understand this query, I haven't dealt with `CASE` before.

Comment: By default case return NULL if doesnt match so should be like this `CASE WHEN users_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END` So if `user_id = 1` is on the group the count will be 1.

Comment: I tried it, it still returns both `groups_id` 1 and 2.

Comment: And it makes sense to me why it returns both, because both `users_id` are in groups 1 and 2.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the result you expect?

Comment: I mentioned it already, I only expect a `groups_id`(in this example will be groups_id 1) with the only two specified members 1 and 2.

Comment: Ok try now. I include a test Fiddle